# OOB score graph for multiclass random forrest. (OneVsRest)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random-forest

I apologize, I will lazily copy paste my code... Issue that I am trying to solve is drawing OOB error graph for 3 class problem, (for three different classifiers). Similarly to http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_ensemble_oob.html.

1. Issue.

Code returns, that ''label" is not defined, of the ordered dictionary, even though i created it. There is comment on particular line. Anyone can spot an issue with the code???

```
min_estimators = 5
max_estimators = 250

estimator_list = estimator_01.estimators_ # List of estimators
labels_list = ['Binary OneVsRest estimator predicting agressiveness', 'Binary OneVsRest estimator predicting passiveness', 'Binary OneVsRest estimator predicting submissiveness'] #List of labels
estimators_dict = OrderedDict((label, []) for label, _ in zip(labels_list, estimator_list))


for i in range(min_estimators, max_estimators + 1):
    for label, est in zip(labels_list, estimator_list):   

        estimator_01.set_params(estimator__n_estimators=i, estimator__oob_score=True, estimator__warm_start=True)
        estimator_01.fit(x_train, y_train)

        oob_error = 1 - est.oob_score_
        estimators_dict[label].append((i, oob_error)) 

for label, clf_err in estimators_dict.items():
    xs, ys = zip(*clf_err)
    plt.plot(xs, ys, label=label)

plt.xlim(min_estimators, max_estimators)
plt.xlabel("n_estimators")
plt.ylabel("OOB error rate")
plt.title('Random Forrest classifier predicting pre-flop actions. OOB rate.')
plt.show()
```

MAXYMOO ANSWERED IT. CODE HAD BEEN UPDATED ACCORDINGLY.

2. Issue

For some reason it produces, three univariate lines, which is literally is not possible. Any ideas why is so? I am attaching the graph.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include `label` in your for loop, you need to have this:

```
 for label, est in zip(label_list, estimator_list):
```